# iPhone TCP Communication

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, tcp

I'm looking for a "simple" use of a TCP packet transfer between iphone and server.

I guess it's mainly open socket, specify port & IP and press send. (it's what I usually do with Python)

Anyone know of a quickstart guide or a "for dummies" kind of tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty good article: [iPhone Network Programming](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43551)

Comment: no problem. it helped me a lot when i was in a hurry to write a simple client. maybe you'll have to change some code if your're using ARC but it's just one or two lines

Answer (score 2):

In iPhone SDK you can do posix socket programming (just as you would in any other unix based operating system). There are plenty of examples on how to do that.

But, unless you are just doing it for learning purposes, **do consider** using HTTP for client/server communication between iOS client and server. It will make your life much easier. Server **AND** client side.

If you want to do a HTTP query in iPhone, your code looks as simple as:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL urlWithString: @"http://eexample.com/page.php?param=2323"];
NSString* stringForUrlPath = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: url 
                                                  encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                     error: nil];
// in stringForUrlPath you will hold whatever the server responded you
```

Comment: Ill consider using HTTP for further research as I am currently only looking to send a "on" hex packet in order to turn on a projector. I think maybe simple socket programming will do the trick.  Thanks!